# Nodejs Https server (Is it safe to put cert file address in code)

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run a node JS application via https on a DMZ server here is a sample:

```
const https = require('https')

const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT

const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

const certificate = process.env.CERTIFICATE_PATH

const _env = process.env.ENV

const httpsOptions = { key: fs.readFileSync(privateKey), cert: fs.readFileSync(certificate) }

if (_env === "PRODUCTION") {

   https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port, function () {

      console.log('Https server running on port :' + port)

   })

} else {

   app.listen(port, () => {

      console.log(' HTTP SERVER Running on port :' + port)

   })

}
```

The problem I have is that I need to reference the certificate paths on the code and this may be an issues if the sever is hacked

Is there any other way I can reference the certificates and its private key without having to specify the physical path ?

Comment: Why do you think that it will be an issue if the server is hacked? I can't see any issue there.

Comment: Yes it is totally safe because if the hacker get the address even by some magic in your code it can download it from your server only possible way could be hacking your memory addresses

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your server is hacked, then all your data is compromised. I mean, if hacker got root access. In other cases, he will not be able to read the source of .js files (of course, if everything else on your server is configured correctly).

In any case, for production ecosystems, it make sense to run a separate front-end server (physical or virtual), save your keys there, run reverse proxy server software (for example, Nginx) and accept secure connection there and then proxy connection to your first working server (with Node.js). This way you'll rise your security and will be able to do some cool tricks with load balancing in the future.

You can read more [here](https://radiostud.io/configuring-nginx-reverse-proxy-node-js-application/) and [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/).

Comment: Thank you Tarkh, i will spend some time learning about Nginx.